# Console Log Color Meaning

Tags: javascript, console, frontend, console.log

I'm curious what's the difference between numbers that show up the color black or blue in the console log?

I'm currently outputting using this variable:

```
currentImageIndex = currentImage.attr('data-index'),
```

It does output the correct number in the console. It shows the number in the color black. For some reason, even though the correct number is outputted, my function doesn't work. But if I write the following:

```
currentImageIndex = 5,
```

the function will work. I notice the number shows up as the color blue in the console log. What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black indicates a string, blue indicates a number:

[image]

Element attributes are always strings; `.attr` returns a string. You need to convert it to a number:

```
currentImageIndex = Number(currentImage.attr('data-index'));
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for my problem! This makes total sense too, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value of your `data-index` attribute is a string, not a number (number are shown as blue in the console).

You should parse the value of the attribute as a number using `window.parseInt` to parse the string as a number:

```
...
const currentImageIndexValue = currentImage.attr('data-index');
const currentImageIndex = window.parseInt(currentImageIndexValue);
```

Just be careful that, if the value of the attribute cannot be parsed as a number, the value of `currentImageIndex` will be `NaN`.

Some details on JavaScript types: [MDN JavaScript types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)